# Django how to pass message in return redirect?

Tags: django, django-views, django-messages

I want to pass a 'success' message to the post, after a new comment is added. Here are the views:

```
@login_required
def add_comment(request, post_slug):  

    p= Article.objects.get(slug=post_slug)
    cform = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if cform.is_valid():
        c = cform.save(commit = False)
        c.post = p
        c.body = cform.cleaned_data['body']
        c.author = request.user
        c.save()
            messages.success(request, "Comment was added") 
     else:
            messages.error(request, "Comment Invalid!") 

    return redirect('article.views.post_withslug', post_slug=post_slug)
```

and

```
def post_withslug(request, post_slug):
    post = Article.objects.get(slug = post_slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    d = dict(post=post, comments=comments, form=CommentForm(), 
             user=request.user)
    d.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("article/post.html", d)
```

The problem is that, messages are not displayed immediately after redirecting to post with new comment. They are displayed however, when I navigate to other pages.

I guess this is because the `context_instance = RequestContext(request)` is not properly conveyed from comment to post views. So I tried other redirect methods like `render_to_respons` and `redner(reverse(` , but could 
not manage to solve the issue. So appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `post_withslug` view. You are not actually using a RequestContext in that view. `d` is a standard dictionary. So, context processors will not be run and the messages will not appear.

You should use the `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response`:

```
return render(request, "article/post.html", d)
```

Comment: Many thanks Daniel! changing to `render` solved the problem. Don't know what I didn't notice it.